# React16.4 setState with an array from fetch() does not work

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, setstate

Exactly the same line this.setState({ allInit }) in code below works fine with string and number states (viewMode or numberInit), but NOT for arrays (allInit or initiatives). 
After entire morning unsuccessful googling, any hint is much appreciated!

```js
export class ContextProvider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      allInit: [],
      initiatives: [1, 2, 3],
      viewMode: 'map',
      numberInit: 248
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('../../json/allinit.json')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(({ allInit }) => {
        this.setState({ allInit }); //this line does not work for array value
        console.log(allInit); // Array of 208 objects
      });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.allInit); // empty array []
    return (
      <Context.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried initializing the allInit state with the blank object, like `allInit : {}` ?

Comment: Please post sample contents of `allinit.json` that fails.

Comment: Are you sure that your provided example is the same as your real code? [Works just fine on 16.6.3](https://jsfiddle.net/z5pvunto/). It has to be something you didn't add to question.

Comment: @VikasSingh: allInit: {} makes no sense, but I did try. Doesn't help ;-(

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli allinit.json is loaded fine! but here http://staging.baselgovernance.org/sites/default/files/allinit.json

Comment: @Solo: Yes, it is the real code. Funny enough, the same code works fine for me in other React16.4 project. I did try to do this setState on other normal component (not Context) but no success.

Comment: Thanks for all the helps! Spent another day on it, but no luck beside a hint: It has to do with asynchronization of fetch(). 1-Console.log(allInit) prints twice, one is empty and one has value [screenshot](https://www.screencast.com/t/7TlaosHFz0). 2-Browser inspector [shows it is empty](https://www.screencast.com/t/LioinBal) but React Tools shows that [Context.allInit has value](https://www.screencast.com/t/cxVbcb5nES). 3-And yes, I have tried all the tips regarding asynchronize instructed [here](https://daveceddia.com/watch-out-for-undefined-state/) but still no LUCK!

Comment: The first time it renders it correctly is empty since the fetch has not completed so you get you initial state. Once the fetch completes, though, it should re-render with the correct data.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli: Yes, agreed! fetch() is a promise call, meaning React continues to load other components while fetch() is working. Problem is Context.Consumer components got mounted while fetch data has NOT arrived yet. I don't know how to make React waits for the data before mounting other components, those relies on the data. To move on, I use php to load and write data into "export default [].js" and import it in components requiring this data. This solution is probably ridiculous for all the React heroes out there, but well ... any helps to solve this with React is much appreciated!